# How to write @Bean for a class?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Following is my employee class. If I write a @Bean annotation to Line 1, Line 2 or Line 3 it throws an error.

It allows the @Bean annotation to method names only. 
Why?

```java
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

    //line 1
    public class Employee {

        int id;
        String name;

        // line 2
        public Employee(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        //line 3
        public Employee() {
        }

        @Bean
        public void showCurrentEmployee() {
            System.out.println(this.id + " " + this.name);
        }

    }
```

and As the Spring world says; Bean scope is a singleton. Where does that apply here? 
How the @Bean method would hold the singleton instance and of what?

If @Bean can not be given to the class name then how the following thing is valid ?

```html
<bean name="emp" class="com.myProj.Employee"> 
<property name="id"> 
      <value>20</value> 
</property> 
<property name="name"> 
      <value>John</value> 
</property> 
</bean>
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html look at this document. it will help you

Comment: Please don't link to documentation that isn't relevant anymore. The Spring Java Config project has been dead for several years now. Parts of it (and lessons learned) have been incorporated into Spring itself.

Comment: Bean scope is singleton by default in Spring. That means that exists only one instance of this class. Spring creates it the first time it will be used. It will be managen from Spring and will be injected on every reuse.

Comment: @Elio, but my Employee class can have multiple instances.

Comment: I am not sure if what you need is a `@Bean` or maybe an `@Entity`? What is the Empoyee class in your case, is it an entry in database or is it a service?
See this two links about the scope of `@Bean` in Spring. They maybe help to better understand what you need in you case:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes OR 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm

Answer (score 1):

@Bean annotation could be used only in Spring configuration classes. This classes should be annotated with @Configuration annotation

With properties injection the @Value annotation could helps.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass {
   @Bean
   public BeanClassOne beanOne(@Value("20") Integer intValue) {
      return new BeanClassOne(intValue);
   }

   @Bean
   public BeanClassTwo beanTwo() {
      return new BeanClassTwo();
   }

   @Bean
   public BeanClassThree beanThree() {
      return new BeanClassThree();
   }
}
```

Another way to make Spring bean from the class to annotate it with @Service or @Component annotation

```
@Service
public class BeanClass {

    @Value("String value")
    privat String strField;
    // your bean methods
}
```

More info here 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

Comment: so my above implementation is wrong ?

Comment: Your third return type is BeanClassThree  but actually returning BeanClass.

Comment: @Rashin fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @user2746466 yes. You are using Bean annotation wrongly. This annotation is analog of <bean> tag in XML spring configurations and could be used only in so called Java configurations. Example of it you can see in my answer.

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski, I have edited the question, please see my explanation

Comment: @user2746466 read about Value annotation. I believe that could help you. 
https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2096/playing-around-with-spring-bean-configuration